# The world is deserted, but why?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, post-apocalypse

### *Scenario:*

I just woke up on the outskirts of a large city. I have nothing more than my clothes and my cell phone (which's battery had run out). I investigate the situation and come to a terrible conclusion - I am all alone in a deserted city. It's not destroyed, however. Buildings are fine, no glass is broken, shops are full of products and no corpses are lying around. And yet, everyone is gone. I took a laptop from one of the shops, but strangely, it doesn't turn on. The batteries are dead and the electric lines are cold, so I went on beyond the city. Some hours later I find an old solar power plant a few miles away that seemed to be pumping. I connected my laptop and accessed the internet, but what I found was even more surprising; The whole world population disappeared withoud a trace.

### This is where you come in.

I have at least three questions that I want to answer, but currently I'm unable to because of my limited resources;

1. Why did humanity vanish?
2. How did it happen without any damage to the infrastructure?
3. How come I'm the only one left?

And no, I'm fairly sure this is not a Matrix-esque simulation or some alien experiment. I want to find the most plausible solution to this conundrum that would work in the real world. In the meantime I'll try to not lose my sanity.

Wish me luck!

Comment: This is very broad, Worldbuilding SE is for answering specific questions, not writing the story for you.

Comment: Welcome to the site Rotterdam, Josh is correct.  While your question is interesting it doesn't fit the format of the SE network particularly well.  You should have a specific question for which a correct (or at least best) answer can be objectively identified.  If you were to keep only question number two and provide some constraints (technology level, sociopolitical climate etc) I think this question could work.

Comment: If you have questions on how to write good questions/answers check out the [help] and feel free to visit [chat] once you have 20 rep.

Comment: Inside the shops that still have product, what does the product look like?  Is there a store with food?  Is it rotten, or fresh?  What does the vegetation look like in the city?  Is it overgrown?  Basically, how recently have your denizens departed?  Are there any signs of their departure?

Comment: you are just dreaming, wake up now. :D

Comment: Also note that "idea generation" style questions are discouraged.

Comment: Anything is possible, just pick whatever reason you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

### God lifted everyone else to Heaven

That's really about the only answer to your question.

As for #3, well, you should have read the fine print before accepting that job as caretaker... On the bright side, your shift ends in 7 times 7 years.

Answer (score 1):

You have suffered a mental breakdown which is manifesting itself as this delusion of total isolation.  You are not really alone, but your mind refuses to recognize that anyone else is here.

This would be a great premise for a story except that for most people, the most realistic responses to such an misperception, would lead to actions which would get them either run over or arrested.

Comment: This was my second choice, but the odds of making it to a remote city without hitting an unseen car are so low I went with the Divine one. Still worth a +1.